# Open or closed set of converging sequence

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

I have come across a question regarding whether a set is open or closed... Needing to give details of why its open or closed..

$C_0 $ the set of sequences converging to $0$ in $(\ell^{\infty} ,||\cdot||_\infty)$

I really don't know where to start with this....

Answer (score 1):

You can show that $\ell_{\infty} \backslash c_0$ is open:

Let $x=(x_n) \in \ell_{\infty} \backslash c_0$. Then, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for any $N >0$, $|x_n|>\epsilon$ for some $n>N$. Now let $y=(y_n) \in \ell_{\infty}$ such that $||x-y||_{\infty}<\epsilon/2$; if $|x_n|>\epsilon$, then $|y_n|>|x_n|-||x-y||_{\infty}>\epsilon/2$. You deduce that $y$ does not converge to $0$, ie. $y \in \ell_{\infty} \backslash c_0$.

Another possibility is to introduce $f : \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} \ell_{\infty} & \to & [0,+ \infty) \\ (x_n) & \mapsto & \limsup\limits_{n \to + \infty} |x_n| \end{array} \right.$. Then $c_0=f^{-1}(0)$ is closed because $f$ is continuous.